# Understanding the "Mutual Recursion Issue" for the Return Type of Functions

Tags: c++, recursion, mutual-recursion

I know the problem of recursive definition of types in C++ for member variables:

```
#include "B.h"
class A
{
    B b;
};
```

---

```
#include "A.h"
class B
{
    A b;
};
```

The compiler complains about this because it is not possible to allocate the memory in this recursive fashion.

What I don't understand is that this seems to apply to function definitions as well:

```
#include "B.h"
class A
{
    B foo();
};
```

---

```
#include "A.h"
class B
{
    A bar();
};
```

The compilers gives the same error:

```
error: ‘A’ does not name a type
error: ‘B’ does not name a type
```

Why is that? It does not make sense to me that the compiler needs to reserve space for the return type. Should I solve this problem with pointers and forward declaration? In my experience (coming from Java), it is quite common that programmers do these recursive definitions to design software. It seems so hard to realize this in C++.

Comment: Yes space needs to be reserved for the return value.  Java returns all class objects by reference.

Comment: Forward reference is enough to solve your inter dependency.

Comment: Was my question bad? I wonder why there are downvotes. Maybe someone can give me some feedback and I can improve next time. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as function definitions go, all you need is an appropriate forward declaration:

```
class A;
class B;

class A
{
    B foo();
};

class B
{
    A bar();
};
```

This will compile with no issues. Feel free to chop this up into two separate header files, with an appropriate forward declaration instead of an `#include`.

Note that the reason you can't declare class members the same way is because this will effectively have a class contain itself. Unfortunately, if that was possible, the end result would be a massive black hole that will swallow all life as we know it, and we certainly don't want that to happen...

Anyway, the other point that you need to keep in mind is you are affected here by your Java background. Classes work fundamentally different in C++ than they do in Java, despite the deceivingly similar syntax. You're better off forgetting everything you know about how classes work in Java. Otherwise you'll keep getting off track, like that. In Java, a similar set of declarations does not result in a class effectively containing itself, but in C++ it does. This is because in Java every class instance is really a pointer to a class, but in C++ it is the class itself, in flesh and blood.

In C++, the real equivalent to this kind of a recursive class declaration would be:

```
class A
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
};

class B
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> A;
};
```

(ignoring for the moment the requisite forward declarations that apply here, too).

And this'll work in C++ equally well as it works in Java (the `std::shared_ptr<>` part is the equivalent of Java's object reference counting, sort-of).  ***This*** is what's equivalent to your similar construct in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You need a **forward declaration**:

```
class B;    // forward declaration

class A
{
    B foo();
};

class B
{
    A bar();
};
```

The declaration above tells the compiler that `class B` exists but not what it looks like.  This is enough to use it as a parameter or return type of a function or method.  Then you can follow up with the actual definition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I knew that I can solve it with forward declaration but was not sure if it was the right or best way. If your code is split up in separate header files, I think another "class A;" is needed in file for class B.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is that this seems to apply to function
>   definitions as well:

Functions can be inlined by the compiler, and the only way to do that is when you know the exact layout of the return type. ***And besides, the compiler must know how to construct the return type of the function***

---

Note: The Compiler doesn't need to know the full definition of the return type of a function declaration, however, it does need to know about it at the definition.

```
//file A.h
class B;  //forward declaration

class A
{
    B foo();   //declaration
};
```

---

```
//file A.cpp
#include "B.h"

B A::foo(){ ....  }  //definition
```

---

```
//file B.h
class A; //forward declaration
class B
{
    A bar();  //declaration, works
    A moo() { .... } //Declaration + Definition, Fails to see full definition of `A`
};
```

---

```
//file B.cpp
#include "A.h"

A B::boo() { ... }
```